# What is the right way to access multidimensional json array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json, cookies, multidimensional-array

I'm working on cookies that contain multidimensional JSON object array and I have bit of a problem accessing them. Kindly help me.

Here's a look at my problem:
I access the values from the html element and encode it before storing it into a variable,

```
var cookie_items = JSON.stringify({id: value, quantity: 1});
```

then I push this object into an array,

```
cookie_array.push(cookie_items);
```

finally, I push the cookie_array into another array with the associative name 'all',

```
final_cookie_array['all'] = cookie_array;
```

When I log final_cookie_array in the browser console, the output looks like this:

```
Object {all: Array[2]}
  all: Array[2]
    0: "{"id":"6","quantity":1}"
    1: "{"id":"2","quantity":1}"
```

When I echo the cookie array in PHP, i.e., $_COOKIE['cookie_name']; it outputs the following:

```
[object Object]
```

But when I try echoing $_COOKIE['cookie_name']['all']; nothing gets displayed.

Can somebody please help me deal with this?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you get when you expand the [object Object] in your browser console?

Comment: [object Object] is echoed on the web page not in the console.

Comment: Is there anywhere were you perform `json_decode` on the cookie in the PHP?

Comment: Oh, my bad, try print_r($_COOKIE['cookie_name']);

Comment: @Scuzzy even echo json_decode($_COOKIE['cookie_name'], true); doesn't print anything!

Comment: @Crazysheep print_r($_COOKIE['cookie_name']); gives the same output: [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

Try like example below

```
<?php
   $json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
   $arr = json_decode($json,true);
   var_dump($arr);
?>
```